# How to find IP Location in PHP?

Tags: php

**Introduction**

I have written following `PHP` code to find location based on `IP address`. But this code works properly at client side and does not work on server. What may be the problem?

**Code**

```
echo $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));    
echo "<br>".$details->country; 
echo "<br>".$details->region; 
echo "<br>".$details->city;
echo "<br>".$details->loc; 
echo "<br>".$details->postal; 
echo "<br>".$details->org;
```

**Problem**

This code only shows `ip address` (executed first line only) and not showing any other details of location.

Comment: "doesn't work" is useless as a problem description. What exactly happens? What errors appear? What's in your log files?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you be a little specific about the issue?

Comment: Can you dump the value of $ip in the location you say this isn't working?

Comment: Please add the return value of file_get_contents() and the return value of json_decode() to your question. Use the `var_dump()` function to print the value of these functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not seeing your error message, I'm going to go ahead and assume `file_get_contents` has been blocked.

[CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) the url, much more reliable.

```
<?php

echo $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"
));
$details = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);

echo "<br>".$details->ip;
echo "<br>".$details->country;
echo "<br>".$details->region;
echo "<br>".$details->city;
echo "<br>".$details->loc;
echo "<br>".$details->postal;
echo "<br>".$details->org;
```

Comment: an upvote and "approving answer" is also a great form of appreciation ;) Glad I could hlep

Answer (score -1):

Your server's IP address can be found as follows:

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` gives you client or requesting browser/machine's IP address.